# Is this map the Gauss map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed compact smooth oriantable manifold. Let $E\to M$ be the normal bundle of the embedding and $N\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a (closed) tubular neighbourhood. $N$ is an $n$-manifold with boundary and $\partial N$ an $(n-1)$-manifold.

The *Gauss map* $G:\partial N\to S^{n-1}$ sends an element $v$ of $\partial N$ to the normalized normal vector pointing from $v$ outwards ([image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map)).

**How can I define this map more rigorously? I.e., how can I make ''pointing from $v$ outwards'' more precise?**

Now $\partial N$ is homotopic to the total space $E'$ of the sphere bundle $E'\to M$ of $E$.

Let $T$ be the tangent bundle of $M$ and $E\oplus T\cong \mathbb{R}^n\times M$ the trivial bundle on $M$. The inclusion $E\subset E\oplus T\cong \mathbb{R}^n\times M$ of vector bundles on $M$ restricts to sphere bundles and composing with the projection is
$$
G':\partial N\cong E'\to (S^{n-1}\times M)\to S^{n-1}
$$

**How can I see that $G'$ is homotopic to the Gauss map $G$?**

Comment: Pointing outwards is easy: a vector $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to point outwards in $\nu \in \partial N$ if $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that for every $s\in (0,\epsilon)$, $\nu + s w \not\in N$. The second requires some thought.

Comment: @WillieWong: Yes, I see, thanks for the answer to the first question.

Comment: For the second question, I sketch what I think should be a method. By definition of the tubular neighborhood you have that $N \setminus M$ is diffeomorphic to $E' \times (0,1]$. For $s\in (0,1]$ let $N_s$ be the image of $E'\times \{s\}$. Let $G_s$ be the Gauss map associated to $N_s$. You directly compute that as $s\to 0$ $G_s \to G'$ continuously.　This establishes $G_s$ as the homotopy.